# iOS Crop Video File to Faces

Tags: ios, swift, video, core-image, core-video

My goals are:

1) Read in a video file from disk to an array of `CMSampleBuffer`s.
2) For each sample buffer, convert it to a `CIImage`.
3) On each image, run face detection and get the bounds of the face.
4) Crop each image to that bounds.
5) After producing an array of `CIImage`s, write that back to a temporary file.

I have a rudimentary implementation that reads in the video:

```
private func retrieveSampleBuffersForAsset(asset: AVAsset) -> [CMSampleBuffer] {
    var samples: [CMSampleBuffer] = []
    do {

        let reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
        if let videoTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).last {
            let videoSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]
            let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: videoSettings)
            reader.addOutput(readerOutput)
            reader.startReading()
            while let sample = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
                samples.append(sample)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        return []
    }
    return samples
}
```

Then I transform the buffers to `CIImage`s and crop them like so:

```
let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: self.context, options: [CIDetectorImageOrientation: NSNumber(integer: 6)])
let features = detector.featuresInImage(self.inputImage)
guard let firstFeature = features.first else {
    return
}

let cropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
let cropRect: CIVector = CIVector(CGRect: firstFeature.bounds)
print(firstFeature.bounds)

cropFilter?.setValue(self.inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
cropFilter?.setValue(cropRect, forKey: "inputRectangle")

self.outputImage = cropFilter?.outputImage
```

For every buffer, I create an image, run it through my custom filter above and crop it. Then I take that outputted cropped image and append it to a list.

Where I'm stuck is the following:

1) This is insanely memory intensive.

I can't get through processing a single video without my application crashing, which makes sense because if you create an image for every buffer, the memory will grow larger and larger.

I was thinking a way around this is to crop the image and then immediately write it to disk using an asset writer and that way I don't have to keep the image around.

2) It's slow.

Face detection is relatively optimized but when I'm trying to do this to all the video assets in my camera roll, the delay is more than noticeable.

Ideally, I'd like to use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to read the files in and get sample buffers from there but I'm not sure how.